# Bucle infinito con método get en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, get

Tengo un componente el cual tiene un método get (getFormulario) en el ts, he puesto un console.log y he podido comprobar que se forma un bucle infinito pero no logro averiguar como solucionarlo. Me sucede lo mismo con otros componentes en los que he puesto el método get pero el formulario lo tengo como private así que la única forma que veo de obtenerlo es mediante el método getter.

Este es el html del componente.

```
<div class="container">
<form class="mt-5" [formGroup]="getFormulario()" (ngSubmit)="loginAction()">
    <h1 class="h1">Iniciar Sessión</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usuario">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email">

        <div class="error" *ngIf="getFormulario().controls.email.errors?.required && getFormulario().controls.email.touched">
            <p>El campo email no puede estar vacio</p>
        </div>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="getFormulario().controls.email.errors?.maxlength && getFormulario().controls.email.touched">
            <p>El campo email solo puede tener un máximo de 50 carácteres</p>
        </div>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="getFormulario().controls.email.errors?.email && getFormulario().controls.email.touched">
            <p>Email no válido.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">

        <div class="error" *ngIf="getFormulario().controls.password.errors?.required && getFormulario().controls.password.touched">
            <p>El campo contraseña no puede estar vacio</p>
        </div>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="getFormulario().controls.password.errors?.maxlength && getFormulario().controls.password.touched">
            <p>El campo contraseña solo puede tener un máximo de 16 carácteres</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"[disabled]="!getFormulario().valid" >
    </div>
</form>
```

Y esto de aquí es el ts, el método esta abajo

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UsuarioLogin } from '../models/usuarioLogin.model';
import { AlertifyService } from '../Services/alertify.service';
import { LoginService } from '../Services/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  private formulario: FormGroup;
  private user: UsuarioLogin;
  private returnedUser: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService, private alertify: AlertifyService) {
    this.formulario = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(16)
      ])
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginService.setLogeado(false);
  }

  getFormulario() {
    console.log("hola");
    return this.formulario;
  }

}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega los mensajes de error que se pueden desplegar tanto en la consola de angular como en el navegador.

Comment: Sospecho que en realidad no es un bucle infinito. La función `getFormulario` se está llamando desde los `*ngIf`, así que Angular para bien o para mal, está llamando a esa función cada vez que detecta un cambio (simplemente mover el ratón) en la aplicación. Así que lo que realmente pasa es que se llama a esa función muchas veces, pero por increíble que parezca así es como funciona Angular. Aunque se puede afinar este comportamiento no es sencillo: https://blog.irontec.com/angular-changedetector-ngzone-y-asyncpipe/

Comment: esto es algo esperado en angular. No deberías preocuparte por esto a menos que tengas problemas de rendimiento. Tal como dice el amigo de arriba esto se debe al change detection de angular. en vez de usar un método puedes usar `get formulario(){ return this.formulario; }`. El comportamiento será parecido pero así no tendrás que ejecutar el método en la template